# Reload a spring batch Job

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

We need to change an already running job. We should be able to push the job change without restarting the server.

Is it possible to reload a Spring batch job after the jobs / application context has been loaded.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail.. the background context.. why such a need arose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DefaultJobLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/DefaultJobLoader.html) allows you to reload the application context for your jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic job deployment and editing of deployed job configurations (without requiring a server restart) is a feature we implemented in Trooper Batch profile (built on Spring Batch and Spring Batch admin). Screen shots are here : https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/wiki/Writing-Batch-jobs-in-Trooper